# Programmatically post status on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I'd like to programmatically post a status on Facebook for a given User ID using C#. How might I go about accomplishing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Get access to the facebook API and then read their documentation. http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Their documentation seems to focus on posting from client code via Javascript.  Is there a specific section that addresses the original poster's desire to post from server-side code in C#?

Comment: They recently discontinued their C# SDK, so you'll have to look at their updated documentation for what they now call "Graph" i think it is.